# Cypress access to an iframe into another iframe

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to find a solution to access to an iframe into an iframe using cypress.
I have already tried all the following function without success:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getIframeBody', (iframeSelector) => {
    // get the iframe > document > body
    // and retry until the body element is not empty
    return cy
    .get(iframeSelector)
    .its('0.contentDocument.body').should('not.be.empty')
    // wraps "body" DOM element to allow
    // chaining more Cypress commands, like ".find(...)"
    // https://on.cypress.io/wrap
    .then(cy.wrap)
  })

Cypress.Commands.add('iframev3', { prevSubject: 'element' }, (iframeSelector, callback) => {
    // For more info on targeting inside iframes refer to this GitHub issue:
    // https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/136
    cy.log('Getting iframe body')

    return cy
        .get(iframeSelector)
        .wrap($iframe)
        .should(iframe => expect(iframe.contents().find('body')).to.exist)
        .then(iframe => cy.wrap(iframe.contents().find('body')))
        .within({}, callback)
})

Cypress.Commands.add('iframeV4', { prevSubject: 'element' }, $iframe => {
    return new Cypress.Promise(resolve => {
        $iframe.ready(function() {
          resolve($iframe.contents().find('body'));
        });
    });
  });
```

I have also tried the iframe plugin.

And I try to access it with this method for example:

```
cy.get('#m_c_layoutElem_cmsdesktop').iframeV4()
        .get('#m_c_layoutElem_contentview', {timeout: 10 * 1000}).iframeV4().debug()
```

But it is always the same I am able to grab the first iframe but not the second one!

REgards,

**EDIT:**
Thanks to the current comments I have advance a little bit and here is the current state:

```
cy.getIframeBody('#m_c_layoutElem_cmsdesktop')
        .then(iframe1 => {   
            let iframe2 = iframe1.find('#m_c_layoutElem_contentview')[0]   //Do stuff with queryselector()   
            console.log(iframe2);
            let iframe3 = iframe2.contentWindow.document.querySelector('#m_c_plc_lt_ctl00_HorizontalTabs_l_c');
            console.log('iframe3', iframe3) // This is set to an iframe
            console.log(iframe3.contentWindow) //This is null
            //debugger

            /*let cyIframe3 = Cypress.$(iframe3.contentWindow.document);
            console.log('cy iframe3', cyIframe3);
*/            
            let cyIframe32 = cy.get(iframe3);
            console.log('cy iframe32', cyIframe32); //This is: $Chainer {userInvocationStack: "    at Context.eval (http://localhost:8090/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\support\index.js:237:25)", specWindow: Window, chainerId: "chainer1656", firstCall: false, useInitialStack: false}

            /*let field = iframe3.contentWindow.document.querySelector('#m$c$f$Title$txtText'); // Exception because iframe3.contentWindow is null
            console.log(field);
*/
            iframe3.find('#m$c$f$Title$txtText').type('Coucou'); //fin is not a function
        });
```

Comment: No luck with `cy.get('iframev3')
  .then(($iframe) => {
    const $iframe = $iframe.contents().find('iframev4')` ?

Comment: I faced a similar situation and this is what I wrote to resolve, But not sure it will work in your case, but do give it a try - `cy.getIframeBody('iframe1 locator').then(iframe1 => {
  let iframe2 = iframe1.find('iframe2 locator')[0]
  //Do stuff with queryselector()
  let getText = iframe2.contentWindow.document.querySelector('locator').innerText
})`

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your proposals. I have some results with the second method but now that I have my iframe2.contentWindow.document I am able get it back into a cy object to continue using the cy api with the find, type, ...?

Answer (score 7):

Don't know if this is going to help you or if you already fixed it, but I did find a solution to access an iframe inside another iframe, cause I was trying to solve that issue for myself, will leave the answer here and hope it can help.

So an example of the id of the iframes:

- Iframe1, id='first_iframe"
- Iframe2, id='second_iframe"

Here is the code sample you can try:

```js
cy.get('#first_iframe').then($firstIframe => {
  const $secondIframeReference = $firstIframe.contents().find('#second_iframe');

  cy.wrap($secondIframeReference).as('secondIframeReference'); // Saving this as a reference so we can access it again using get command

  // Now we are accessing the second iframe
  cy.get('@secondIframeReference').then($secondIframe => {
    const $elementYouWant = $secondIframe.contents().find('element you want to interact with');

    cy.wrap('$elementYouWant').type("It's writing some stuff"); // In case it is an input field, for example
  });
});
```

Got into this solution after reading this [article](https://medium.com/@ahmadkabakibi/cypress-io-iframe-best-practices-4d850199a570)

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple. There are two ways. (Following are Real reproducible examples)

```js
it("Using 'contentDocument' property and its() - Nested iFrames", function() {
        cy.visit("https://www.play1.automationcamp.ir/frames.html")
        cy.get("#frame1")
            .its('0.contentDocument')
            .its('body')
            .find("#frame2")
            .its('0.contentDocument')
            .its('body')
            .find("#click_me_2").click()

    })
    
it("Using yielded jQuery element - Nested iFrames", function() {
        cy.visit("https://www.play1.automationcamp.ir/frames.html")
        cy.get("#frame1").then(function($iFrame1){
            const iframe2 = $iFrame1.contents().find('#frame2')
            cy.wrap(iframe2).as('iframe2Ref')
            cy.get('@iframe2Ref').then(function($iFrame2){
                const iFrame2Contents = $iFrame2.contents().find('body')
                cy.wrap(iFrame2Contents).find("#click_me_2").click()
            })
        })
    })
```